# why Search function is not working in django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates, django-urls

After I searched on a specific keyword, Django is not retrieving searched items that matches but it's showing all data. When I search for `history` it's showing all books though I have history books on the database.

**`views.py`**

```
def home(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        searchName = request.POST.get('Search')
        if not searchName :
             searchName = ""
        
        context={
            'data': Book.objects.filter(bookname__contains=searchName)
        }
        return render(request, 'library_site/home.html',context)
    else:
        context={
            'data': Book.objects.all()
        }           
    return render(request, 'library_site/home.html',context)
```

**`form field in html`**

```
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'home' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input   class="search-input" type="text"  name="searchBook" placeholder="Search Book Name here...">
    <input   class="btn" type="submit"  name="search" value="Search">                
</form>
```

Comment: because your name attribute, "search," does not match "Search"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the *name attribute* for search input with `searchBook` in your template so change in view like this.

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    searchName = request.POST.get('searchBook', '')
        
    context={
       'data': Book.objects.filter(bookname__contains=searchName)
        }
    return render(request, 'library_site/home.html',context)
```

Comment: Thanks. How can I miss this!!!!-_-. I am regretting myself...